# Have Drupal "gray out" certain fields on a web form when the from is being edited for the 2nd time?

Tags: drupal, entities, drupal-webform

I am trying to create a drupal (entities) web form that a user can fill out and submit. HOWEVER if that user wants to edit that same drupal form again, how to I make certain inputed fields grayed out and non editable when they return?

Also if it possible to have hidden fields only appear when the form is being edited for any time other than when it was organically entered?

Comment: Create a mini-module and use https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7

Check if the fields have values and if so, disable them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and enable the module "Editable Fields". Then, when you are editing the filed that you want "grayed out", there will be an option called, "Field visibility and permissions". Under that click on "Custom Permissions", which will give you the option to uncheck the user's ability to edit the value for that field.

Once that is done, you won't see that field on the edit form anymore. If you want to see it on the edit form "grayed out", then also download and enable the module "Field Readonly". Once it is enabled, nothing more is required to do, it will appear on the form, but you won't be able to edit it.